# How do I generate dll from VC++ project?

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to build a plugin for Miranda IM. I am totally new to Visual Studio. Here are the plugin files source files: http://miranda.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/miranda/trunk/miranda/plugins/testplugin/
How do I compile this to generate a dll? Sorry for my ignorance. I am using VS2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click right mouse button on the Project in solution tree, choose properties->general->Configuration Type, choose "Dynamic Library (.dll)"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The configuration property you said was set to dll. The problem was in the linker output directory. I had converted a old VC++ project and there were some problems because of that.